# Inconveniente con cuadro combinado dentro de hoja de cálcuno en Excel con VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Cordial saludo, les escribo para pedirles el favor con lo siguiente

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente en Excel con Programación en VBA: Vinculo un Cuadro combinado a una hoja de trabajo en Excel, de la cual necesito traer los registros que tengo en un rango de celdas (R2 hasta la R36)
Necesito que al activar la hoja de trabajo me alimente el cuadro combinado con dichos valores, para ello vinculo el componente de programación “cuadro combinado”:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo de la macro es el siguiente:

Dim rango, celda As Range
Set rango = Worksheets("Obtener_Paises").Range("R2:R36")

For Each celda In rango
ComboBox1.AddItem celda.Value
Next celda

Desafortunadamente no veo en donde ver el nombre del componente (Cuadro combinado) o por lo menos ver dónde están las propiedades de dicho objeto, para programarlo  y no me muestre dicho error.
En el siguiente video se explica el requerimiento de lo que necesito:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIobMOU1zZA
Gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola, no uses el cuadro combinado de los formularios, usa el de los controles ActiveX

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, incluí un combobox, con nombre ComboBox1 de tipo ActiveX a la hoja de cálculo y me muestra el mismo error.

Comment: Si lo seleccionas con clic derecho, arriba a la izquierda donde normalmente se muestra la coordenada de la celda activa, verás el nombre del objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Te entendí mejor y veo que usas el evento Open del libro para cargar el combobox. Insisto en que uses uno de los ActiveX, para usar con VBA es mejor, pero eso sí, cuando llenas un combobox de una hoja a través de un evento de otra hoja y/o del libro, tienes que hacer referencia a ella de otro modo. Prueba así:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Celda As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Obtener_Paises")

For Each Celda In ws.Range("R2:R36")
    ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.AddItem Celda.Value
Next Celda
```

Solo verifica el nombre del combobox. Comentas.